# Custom grid with images - responsive issues

Tags: css, joomla, responsive-design, grid

i've created a custom module in joomla to display a gallery in the homepage of the website i'm currently working at: http://www.francescaleso.com/it/

The problem is that my media queries work fine only for desktop or small mobile devices in portrait mode only.

For ipads and mobiles in landscape mode, it messes up everything.

Here's the code, which you can also check with F12 tools:

```
/* the container of the whole gallery, for desktop */
.home-container {
    padding-top: 5%;
    margin-bottom: -2%;
}

@media screen and (max-device-width: 990px) {
    .home-container {
        display: none;
}
}

/* the container of the whole gallery, for mobile devices */
.home-container-mobile {
    padding-top: 0%;
    margin-bottom: -2%;
    margin-top: -10%;
}

@media screen and (min-device-width: 990px) {
    .home-container-mobile {
        display: none;
}
}

/* the container of a single row of items in the gallery */

.grid-container {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

@media screen and (max-device-width: 990px) {
    .grid-container {
    width: 100%;
}
}

/* the gallery single item */

.grid {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-device-width: 990px) {
    .grid {
    width: 43%;
    float: left !important;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 10px;
}
}

/* the gallery single item image */

.grid img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: .4s -webkit-filter linear;
}

.grid:hover img {
  filter: url(filters.svg#grayscale);
     /* Firefox 3.5+ */
  filter: gray;
  /* IE6-9 */
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
}


/* the gallery single item description */

.desc {
    /* display: block; */
    /* position: absolute; */
    left: 26%;
    width: 87%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.desc span {
width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 37%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0%;
    font-size: 16px;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .8s ease 50ms;
    transition: opacity .8s ease 50ms;
    -webkit-transition: background-color ease-in-out 200ms;
    transition: background-color .3s ease-in-out 200ms;
    color: #fff !important;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

@media screen and (max-device-width: 767px) {
    .desc span {
        opacity: 1;
        /* background: rgba(178,189,167,0.7) */
        /* first gradient darker - background: radial-gradient(rgba(72,67,67,0.644444) 20%, rgba(72,67,67,0.37) 77%) !important; */
        background: radial-gradient(rgba(72,67,67,0.444444) 20%, rgba(72,67,67,0.37) 34%) !important
}
}

@media only screen and
(min-device-width: 767px)
(max-device-width: 1025px){
    .desc span {
        width: 68% !important;
        opacity: 1;
        /* background: rgba(178,189,167,0.7) */
        /* first gradient darker - background: radial-gradient(rgba(72,67,67,0.644444) 20%, rgba(72,67,67,0.37) 77%) !important; */
        background: radial-gradient(rgba(72,67,67,0.444444) 20%, rgba(72,67,67,0.37) 34%) !important;
}
}

.grid:hover .desc span {
  opacity: 1;
    /* background: rgba(168,202,217,0.6); */
    /* background: rgba(186, 212, 106, 0.6); */
    /* background: rgba(201, 220, 135, 0.6); */
    /* background: rgba(197, 225, 165, 0.6); */
    /* background: rgba(230, 238, 156, 0.6); */
    background: rgba( 178, 189, 167, 0.7);
}
```

As you can see, in such "intermediate" mobile views, the whole structure gets screwed up: i would like to have 2 columns of items for mobile phones (which i have achieved), and 4 for the other views, like the desktop version.

How can i achieve that?

Is there any other method to get the description div to cover the whole image area without setting a defined width and a height? That seems to be the thing that doesn't work properly...

Thank you for your attention, this really is a great community!

Comment: Questions seeking help ("**why isn't, or how to make, this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary**_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

There two ways you can achieve what you want

**First: define media query for all standard screen sizes like**

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}
/**********
iPad 3
**********/
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}
/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen  and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen  and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 5 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 568px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 568px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 6 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-height: 667px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-height: 667px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 6+ ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-height: 736px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-height: 736px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

/* Samsung Galaxy S3 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

/* Samsung Galaxy S4 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3){
/* Styles */
}

/* Samsung Galaxy S5 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 360px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 360px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3){
/* Styles */
}
```

or you can any css mobile first frame work like Bootstrap, Foundation 3, Foundation etc
just need to add css and use grid layout to achieve clean and standard layout easily.